# WP-API and Basic Auth returning 403 on POST but not GET

Tags: ajax, authentication, wp-api

I am using the latest, WP-API and the recommended Basic Auth, to test adding a post to WP from remote.

I have Access Headers opened up on the WP side:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type");
```

When I submit a Get request to: http://sandbox.ravennainteractive.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts the call easily authenticates and returns the Hello World Post.

When I submit a Post request to the same url. I get an error. Here is my jquery ajax call:

```
$('#test-post').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var title = $( '#title' ).val();
    var content = $( '#content_raw' ).val();

    var postData = {
        title: title,
        content: content
    }

    console.log(postData);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: postData,
        url: sandboxUrl,
        beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', 'Basic '+ btoa( 'apiuser' + ':' + 'PASSWORD' ));
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert('Your comment was successfully added');
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert('There was an error adding your comment');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

The response is  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Array[0]responseText: "[{"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"You don't have permission to do this.","data":{"status":403}}]"

If run this block of code, removing unnecessary extras the query works and returns the Hello World post.

```
 $('#test-post').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: sandboxUrl,
        beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', 'Basic '+ btoa( 'apiuser' + ':' + 'PASSWORD' ));
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert('Your comment was successfully added');
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert('There was an error adding your comment');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `contentType: 'application/json'`?

Comment: `contentType` can be `application/json`, as toscho said, or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. [Both should work](http://wp-api.org/#posts_create-a-post_input") but `json` is not a valid `contentType` value.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, neither of those contentTypes solved the issue but thanks for helping steer me clear of other issues.  I'll update the OP.

Comment: Have you tried Postman or Rest Client to narrow down the issue?  Make sure the browser running it is not logged into your WordPress site (use incognito or similar). PS - how are you sending params using the sandbox url for the get function?

Comment: I have the same experience in postman.  POST fails but GET Works.  I have made sure I am logged out but creating an "apiuser" so that there is never cross over.  In the case of the GET, since I am just asking for posts, there are no params, just pinging the url with a GET.

Answer (score 1):

I've met the same issue.

> ...the recommended Basic Auth...

I found that the problem is in the Basic Auth plugin. WP-API guys [recommend](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1572) using their own plugin and this solution works for me.

1. Deactivate all activated basic auth plugins in your WordPress dashboard
2. On the machine your WordPress is running go to the plugin folder
3. Run

   git clone https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth.git
4. Go to your WordPress admin dashboard, plugins page. *JSON Basic Authentication* should be in the list. Activate it.

Now creating a record via POST request should work.

Comment: Thanks for the note, did you try this in the last few days?  I was using their BasicAuth plugin, I saw the note in the docs saying you had to use theirs.

Comment: I tried this yesterday. POST started working properly once I installed and activated the plugin.

Comment: last question, can you share the plugin version numbers?

Comment: Sure. 'JSON Basic Authentication' - version 0.1 by WordPress API Team. 'WP REST API' version 1.2.4 by WP REST API Team (also I tried version 2.0-beta6, the auth worked properly with it). Wordpress v 4.3.1. Feel free to ask any questions.